# Date and decimal validation ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have model for Persons
Here is class

```
 public partial class Persons
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please write First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please write Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Personal Number is too long")]
    [Remote(action: "PersonalNumberExists", controller: "Persons", ErrorMessage = "Personal Number is duplicated")]
    public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Here is View

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PersonalNumber" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="PersonalNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PersonalNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Birthdate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Birthdate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Birthdate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Salary" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Salary" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Salary" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to make date and decimal validation for Birthdate and Salary fields.
I mean just check is it date or no, for decimal (decimal validation and greater or equals 0)
I don't find any validation for it
How I can do this?

Comment: What validation do you want? What is you code in the view and what is not working?

Comment: Validation is it date for date for example. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Again, What is you code in the view and what is not working?

Comment: Sounds like your `Birthdate` property doesn't have any issues. Maybe you've issue regarding validation in client-side? Also what kind of validation you want for `decimal` type?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated post

Comment: And are you using mvc's client side validation (using `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)? If so, you need to reconfigure the validator (which by default validates dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. And if you want `Salary` to be greater that zero, you can add a `[Range]` attribute to it. BUt you still have not explained what your problem is. What are you expecting to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: I need to check if value in birthday input is date. I wrote this in post. I use validation on server side. you can see this from model @StephenMuecke

Comment: What is your expected result? You may share us your input for `decimal field` and what error you  expect.

Answer (score 0):

For validation, try like below

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required]
public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
public string Gender { get; set; }

[Required]
public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
```